# monitor changes in a file or directory?

Tags: android

In Android, how do I monitor changes made by others (app, internet, bluetooth, dll) to a file or directory

Comment: "dll"? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 28):

I think [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. I just want to use something that uses or similar to inotify.
And it does :D

Answer (score 1):

No, in standard android, you don't monitor for activities of others, app, internet etc.

Your program can only track and access your data directory. Others uses its own directories.

But, if you have rooted a telephone, you can write/start a root process or suid process. But this solution is only valid for rooted telephones..

Comment: "telephones"? Funny how nowadays Android runs on watches, TVs, cars, and whatnot.