# Scan for changes in Android directories

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-memory

My app now has a background service that needs to check if there is any changes in some specific directories chosen by users. If there is any new files, it will be uploaded to a server (like syncing to your Dropbox folder), but if the user deletes a file from his device, the file on server will not be deleted. My problem is I can't find an effective way to detect changes.

I first used recursion to check folder size but clearly the performance is not good at all (the service have to recursively check folders after xxx minutes/seconds, record its size to compare to the next time...).

I tried using DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE, which turns out not a good option either. Firstly, new files can be copied, not only downloaded. Secondly, the broadcastreceiver can only receive requests send from my app, not from other apps or browsers). I check around Google and StackOverFlow but can only find how to scan for Media Files, I need more than that. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is FileObserver  intended for this 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html ?

here is similar
[monitor changes in a file or directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891570/monitor-changes-in-a-file-or-directory)

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but I think it can solve my problems. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to read, btw if your looking for folder size changes use this function,

This function will return you the size in particular folder.

```
public static long folderSize(File directory) {
    long length = 0;
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile())
            length += file.length();
        else
            length += folderSize(file);
    }
    return length;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/size-of-folder-or-file)

Comment: sorry for that, can you show me how to make it easier to read. As I said in my question, this method has to walk the directory tree recursively and I don't want to do that because it lower the performance/